# Number of 1st Jan Sundays between year a and b.

Tags: number-theory, calendar-computations

Given two year number a and b (eg a=1000 b=2000). Find the number of 1st January Sundays? Given 1st Jan 2001 was Monday?

I figured that day sequence repeat after 28 years. But produced wrong answer. Help me figure it out.

PS: This was actually programming question and i wanted to get a O(1) solution.

Comment: Are you sure the sequence is periodic with order $28$?  I think [the leap year rules](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html) are trickier than that (there's the "divisible by $100$ but not by $400$ bit".)

Comment: one part may be that the calendar type changed etc. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY  goes into detail if you go back far enough.